# What is the equivalent of container.RegisterInstance<IServiceA>(IoC.Resolve<IServiceB>()); in the dependency injection container of .NET Core?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, unity-container

I am migrating a .NET Windows Service to .NET Core console app. I want to use the out of the box Dependency Injection of .NET Core instead of unity.

I am hitting a block in translating this line to map to .NET Core DI:

```
container.RegisterInstance<IServiceA>(IoC.Resolve<IServiceB>());
```

IServiceB has been registered as such before in Unity:

```
container.RegisterType<IServiceB, SomeService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

IServiceB has been registered as such in NET Core DI:

```
serviceCollection.AddScoped<IServiceB, SomeService>();
```

From my understanding, container.RegisterInstance(IoC.Resolve()); is mapping IServiceA, to SomeService, correct? Like that SomeService can map both to IServiceA and IServiceB. Or I am understanding something wrongly?

So, I tried something like this:

```
var x = serviceProvider.GetServices<IServiceB>().First(o => o.GetType() == typeof(IServiceA));
serviceCollection.AddScoped<IServiceA, x>();
```

I am however getting the error: "x is a variable but is used like a type."

How should I translate it?

Comment: Why do you have `serviceProvider` there? Surely you should only have that after you have built it from the serviceCollection?

Comment: I didn't know that John, thank you for shedding light on this. This would explain why I had null exceptions at other lines where I used serviceProvider. Thank you.

Comment: `container.RegisterInstance<X>(IoC.Resolve<Y>());` is a very bad idea to begin with. There is a reason that containers like Autofac and MS.DI separate the registration phase and containers like Simple Injector lock the container after the first resolve. For instance, read [this documentation](https://simpleinjector.org/locked), which describes the problem in doing this. That description is container agnostic. Do note that doing `container.Register(container.Resolve)` is a very different pattern from @zaitman's answer, which _delays_ the resolve until after the registration phase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a factory lambda to the `AddScoped` extension like so:

`serviceCollection.AddScoped<IServiceA>(s => s.GetService<IServiceB>())`;